# Can someone explain the basic procedure for creating a table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I've been looking at various examples around the web and reading Apple's docs, but I'm still just having trouble understanding the concept behind how table views are created, laid out, and managed.

I would imagine that they worked like regular views within a view controller and that table cells would just be sub-sub-views, but from what I can tell they require a lot more complicated implementation than just a sub-view.

I just need a quick handle on the general idea behind their implementation from someone that's worked with them before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start up Xcode and create a new project. Select the "Master-Detail Application" project. Once it's created, look at the MasterViewCongtroller.swift file, specifically at the lines under the `// MARK: - Table View` line.

That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest going through some tutorials. Here are a few...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout
http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/

In order to implement a table view you should take a look at [Apple's UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html)

At the bare minimum you want to 1) Add a table view to your storyboard 2) make a class for the table view and in storyboard set the table view's class to the one you created 3) make a referencing outlet into the view controller